# How do you fix this error: MySQL ODBC Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost'?

Tags: mysql, vbscript, asp-classic, odbc, ado

I had used .mdb for my ASP applications. Since I've learned and used php, I, now, want to use ASP applications with MySql databases. However, I get some errors that I cannot figure out.

This is my code:

```
set conn=server.createobject("ADODB.Connection")
bag="DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};UIN=aksar_isilak;PWD=741285;SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=aksarayf_isilak;OPTION=3"
conn.open bag
```

And when I execute it, I get this error message:

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'

[MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver]Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

C:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\ISILAK.COM\HTTPDOCS\YONETIM\../vt.asp, line 6
```

This is not my server, it is an hosting, I can create some ODBC connection on plesk panel, just you to know.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try the recommended connection string format http://connectionstrings.com/mysql#p30

Comment: why dont you write this as an answer because it is worked! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the recommended connection string format; http://connectionstrings.com/mysql#p30 which uses `username`/`password` rather than `UIN?`/`PWD`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's the correct password? Also maybe check permissions of user trying to access the specific database.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your are not passing the right parameter because the message says you're trying to connect using the user "ODBC".

'localhost' is ok since you're running the app in the same server.

Answer (score 0):

UID=user is the normal ODBC attribute, not UIN=user